# Passing data from one element to another on the same html page

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to develop a mobile app. The problem I am having is this, when the user fills in a form on the html page I want the data to get written to an unordered list on the same page. I want when the next user fills data for that dat to get written to the second list item in the list and so on
. 
Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to give with this problem

Comment: How far did you manage to get with this before you came here?

Comment: I have searched the web exhaustively but with no luck. I have a piece of code that works but when the second user fills data that does not written to the list, to be honest it was a very poor effort

Comment: I'm assuming the first user and the second user may access the page several minutes, hours, or days apart. That means you'll need to store each user's data in a database (or figure out some other way to store it). Then, when you load the page, you'll pull the information from the database (or whatever) to show in the UL.

Comment: That sounds like good progress to me, you just need to incorporate some kind of data storage like Brett has suggested by the sound of it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you're trying to make an app that stores the data of each submitting of the forum and returns them to all users that come across the page?

For such tasks you'll need, at least:

- [A web server that runs PHP](http://www.apachefriends.org/), Python or other language to your liking*;
- A database to connect the server-side with (MySQL or PostgreSQL usually);

What you need to do:

- Learn about HTTP POST and basic SQL input/output if you haven't;
- Learn [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/%E2%80%8E) if you haven't;
- Store the user input in the database and have a server script retrieve it on call;
- Update the dynamic page bit (the unordered list) with AJAX (loading a XML file with the PHP script that writes the database info into it should do) every minute or so using a timeout function.

I'll post links to all I've mentioned in a minute.

*NodeJS is getting popular for being asynchronous (making it easier for dynamic pages to interact with the server) and allowing programmers to use the same language client- and server-side, but I have never tried it to tell you how it fares. *Edit: says John NaN: NodeJS is* not *recommended. Again, I don't know it myself; that is why it's on a note and not upper in the post. Good luck!*

*Bonus note: don't trust W3Schools most of the time. The AJAX tutorial I linked to, however, isn't that bad and it's easy to follow.

Comment: Nice answer - saved me finishing a similar one I had started. I'd probably recommend against using NodeJS given what I can guess about the submitters experience level from the question.